# JavaFx Application crashes on Exit

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx-2, semaphore, crash-dumps

I have an Problem with my Java Fx Application.
On exit it crashes with the following error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000709a1e90, pid=712, tid=8400
#
# JRE version: 7.0_25-b17
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.25-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00000000709a1e90[thread 7596 also had an error]

#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\workspaces\hs_err_pid712.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

The logfile includes this:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000709a1e90, pid=712, tid=8400
#
# JRE version: 7.0_25-b17
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.25-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00000000709a1e90
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000001fdf7000):  JavaThread "QuantumRenderer-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=8400, stack(0x0000000023b10000,0x0000000023c10000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, ExceptionInformation=0x0000000000000008 0x00000000709a1e90

Registers:
RAX=0x00000000709a1e90, RBX=0x00000006e5ed7640, RCX=0x000000001fdf71d8, RDX=0x0000000023c0ee40
RSP=0x0000000023c0edb8, RBP=0x0000000023c0ee30, RSI=0x0000000000000007, RDI=0x0000000003d5bbd4
R8 =0x0000000000010001, R9 =0x00000000000000cb, R10=0x000000000270237c, R11=0x0000000069a89860
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x00000006e5ed7640, R14=0x0000000023c0ee58, R15=0x000000001fdf7000
RIP=0x00000000709a1e90, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0000000023c0edb8)
0x0000000023c0edb8:   00000000027023a8 000000001220e4a0
0x0000000023c0edc8:   0000000014402460 0000000200004019
0x0000000023c0edd8:   0000000c00000078 00000006e66cf190
0x0000000023c0ede8:   0000000000000000 0000000023c0edf0
0x0000000023c0edf8:   0000000000000000 0000000023c0ee58
0x0000000023c0ee08:   00000006e5eda738 0000000000000000
0x0000000023c0ee18:   00000006e5ed7640 0000000000000000
0x0000000023c0ee28:   0000000023c0ee50 0000000023c0eea0
0x0000000023c0ee38:   00000000026f6374 0000000703fff258
0x0000000023c0ee48:   00000000026ff1d6 0000000000010001
0x0000000023c0ee58:   0000000703f66780 0000000023c0ee60
0x0000000023c0ee68:   00000006e5ed80dc 0000000023c0eeb8
0x0000000023c0ee78:   00000006e5eda738 0000000000000000
0x0000000023c0ee88:   00000006e5ed80f0 0000000023c0ee50
0x0000000023c0ee98:   0000000023c0eeb0 0000000023c0ef10
0x0000000023c0eea8:   00000000026f63d3 0000000703f66780 

Instructions: (pc=0x00000000709a1e90)
0x00000000709a1e70:   
[error occurred during error reporting (printing registers, top of stack, instructions near pc), id 0xc0000005]

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00000000709a1e90 is an unknown value
RBX=0x00000006e5ed7640 is an oop
{method} 
 - klass: {other class}
RCX=0x000000001fdf71d8 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000023c0ee40 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001fdf7000
RSP=0x0000000023c0edb8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001fdf7000
RBP=0x0000000023c0ee30 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001fdf7000
RSI=0x0000000000000007 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000003d5bbd4 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000010001 is an unknown value
R9 =0x00000000000000cb is an unknown value
R10=0x000000000270237c is an Interpreter codelet
method entry point (kind = native)  [0x0000000002702100, 0x0000000002702980]  2176 bytes
R11=0x0000000069a89860 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x00000006e5ed7640 is an oop
{method} 
 - klass: {other class}
R14=0x0000000023c0ee58 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001fdf7000
R15=0x000000001fdf7000 is a thread


Stack: [0x0000000023b10000,0x0000000023c10000],  sp=0x0000000023c0edb8,  free space=1019k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  0x00000000709a1e90
j  com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline.getResourceFactory(Lcom/sun/glass/ui/Screen;)Lcom/sun/prism/ResourceFactory;+4
j  com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.prism.ps.PPSRenderer.dispose()V+64
j  com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.prism.ps.PPSRenderer$1.factoryReleased()V+4
j  com.sun.prism.impl.BaseResourceFactory.notifyReleased()V+41
j  com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DResourceFactory.notifyReleased()V+42
j  com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline.notifyAllResourcesReleased()V+23
j  com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline.dispose()V+26
j  com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.cleanup()V+9
j  com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run()V+14
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0x1a6844]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline.nGetAdapterOrdinal(J)I+0
j  com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline.getResourceFactory(Lcom/sun/glass/ui/Screen;)Lcom/sun/prism/ResourceFactory;+4
j  com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.prism.ps.PPSRenderer.dispose()V+64
j  com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.prism.ps.PPSRenderer$1.factoryReleased()V+4
j  com.sun.prism.impl.BaseResourceFactory.notifyReleased()V+41
j  com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DResourceFactory.notifyReleased()V+42
j  com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline.notifyAllResourcesReleased()V+23
j  com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline.dispose()V+26
j  com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.cleanup()V+9
j  com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run()V+14
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x000000001fdfb800 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=8240, stack(0x0000000023030000,0x0000000023130000)]
  0x000000001fdfa800 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=8496, stack(0x0000000024f80000,0x0000000025080000)]
  0x000000001402b000 JavaThread "Thread-105" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=8732, stack(0x0000000025390000,0x0000000025490000)]
  0x000000001402c000 JavaThread "JFXMedia Player EventQueueThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8640, stack(0x0000000025150000,0x0000000025250000)]
  0x0000000014028000 JavaThread "Thread-48" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=8420, stack(0x0000000028bb0000,0x0000000028cb0000)]
  0x0000000014027800 JavaThread "JFXMedia Player EventQueueThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7312, stack(0x0000000028ec0000,0x0000000028fc0000)]
  0x0000000014026800 JavaThread "Media Resource Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5648, stack(0x0000000024ce0000,0x0000000024de0000)]
  0x000000001fdfa000 JavaThread "Prism Font Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9160, stack(0x0000000022d50000,0x0000000022e50000)]
  0x000000001fdf9000 JavaThread "Thread-12" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7596, stack(0x0000000024a10000,0x0000000024b10000)]
  0x000000001fdf8800 JavaThread "JavaFX Application Thread" [_thread_in_native, id=9140, stack(0x0000000023dd0000,0x0000000023ed0000)]
  0x000000001fdf7800 JavaThread "Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8796, stack(0x0000000024e30000,0x0000000024f30000)]
=>0x000000001fdf7000 JavaThread "QuantumRenderer-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=8400, stack(0x0000000023b10000,0x0000000023c10000)]
  0x00000000140bc800 JavaThread "Thread-8" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7224, stack(0x000000001b820000,0x000000001b920000)]
  0x0000000014765800 JavaThread "HouseKeeper" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8596, stack(0x000000001d3c0000,0x000000001d4c0000)]
  0x00000000145b3000 JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3540, stack(0x000000001c8c0000,0x000000001c9c0000)]
  0x00000000143e7000 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5544, stack(0x0000000014c60000,0x0000000014d60000)]
  0x000000001222a000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8252, stack(0x0000000013af0000,0x0000000013bf0000)]
  0x0000000012227000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8684, stack(0x00000000139c0000,0x0000000013ac0000)]
  0x0000000012213000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7272, stack(0x0000000013830000,0x0000000013930000)]
  0x0000000012212000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8772, stack(0x0000000013670000,0x0000000013770000)]
  0x000000001220a800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6900, stack(0x00000000134b0000,0x00000000135b0000)]
  0x000000000228e800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8352, stack(0x0000000013370000,0x0000000013470000)]
  0x0000000002287800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9208, stack(0x0000000013200000,0x0000000013300000)]
  0x00000000001ae800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=8356, stack(0x00000000025f0000,0x00000000026f0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000012183000 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000013090000,0x0000000013190000] [id=8520]
  0x0000000013c00800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000012f50000,0x0000000013050000] [id=792]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 323456K, used 116276K [0x00000007aaeb0000, 0x00000007d0d60000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 321152K, 36% used [0x00000007aaeb0000,0x00000007b203d170,0x00000007be850000)
  from space 2304K, 0% used [0x00000007ce420000,0x00000007ce420000,0x00000007ce660000)
  to   space 21888K, 0% used [0x00000007cf800000,0x00000007cf800000,0x00000007d0d60000)
 ParOldGen       total 174208K, used 58619K [0x0000000700c00000, 0x000000070b620000, 0x00000007aaeb0000)
  object space 174208K, 33% used [0x0000000700c00000,0x000000070453ef98,0x000000070b620000)
 PSPermGen       total 217280K, used 97403K [0x00000006e0c00000, 0x00000006ee030000, 0x0000000700c00000)
  object space 217280K, 44% used [0x00000006e0c00000,0x00000006e6b1ee00,0x00000006ee030000)

Card table byte_map: [0x00000000056f0000,0x0000000005ff0000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000001fea000

Polling page: 0x0000000000140000

Code Cache  [0x00000000026f0000, 0x0000000002cd0000, 0x00000000056f0000)
 total_blobs=2619 nmethods=1494 adapters=1075 free_code_cache=43416Kb largest_free_block=44218368

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 207.573 Thread 0x0000000012213000 1646             javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument$LeafElement::getEndOffset (10 bytes)
Event: 207.574 Thread 0x0000000012213000 nmethod 1646 0x0000000002aa5c10 code [0x0000000002aa5d60, 0x0000000002aa5e38]
Event: 207.579 Thread 0x0000000012227000 1647             javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet$ViewAttributeSet::getAttribute (61 bytes)
Event: 207.581 Thread 0x0000000012227000 nmethod 1647 0x00000000029e68d0 code [0x00000000029e6a60, 0x00000000029e6c30]
Event: 207.593 Thread 0x0000000012213000 1648             javax.swing.text.LabelView::sync (12 bytes)
Event: 207.594 Thread 0x0000000012213000 nmethod 1648 0x00000000029e65d0 code [0x00000000029e6720, 0x00000000029e67f8]
Event: 208.679 Thread 0x0000000012227000 1649             oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine::unmarshalSB4 (8 bytes)
Event: 208.679 Thread 0x0000000012213000 1650             oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine::unmarshalDALC (53 bytes)
Event: 208.679 Thread 0x0000000012227000 nmethod 1649 0x0000000002aa4d90 code [0x0000000002aa4ee0, 0x0000000002aa4f68]
Event: 208.681 Thread 0x0000000012213000 nmethod 1650 0x0000000002aa4690 code [0x0000000002aa4800, 0x0000000002aa4a98]

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
java_command: 
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_20_64bit
PATH=C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;c:\dev\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-2.0.9\bin;c:\dev\Apache Software Foundation\apache-ant-1.8.1\bin
USERNAME=af7711
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 58 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

Memory: 4k page, physical 16723516k(8101396k free), swap 33445172k(23323688k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.25-b01) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_25-b17), built on Jun 21 2013 12:58:32 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Tue Aug 20 08:29:31 2013
elapsed time: 208 seconds
```

The source for starting the FX-Application an handling the exit and close events looks like this:

```
private final Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(0);
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        new JFXPanel(); // initializes JavaFX environment
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                stage.setTitle(moduleInfo.getDisplayName());

                stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {

                    @Override
                    public void handle(WindowEvent arg0) {
                        sem.release();
                    }
                });

                stage.setOnHiding(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {

                    @Override
                    public void handle(WindowEvent arg0) {
                        sem.release();
                    }
                });

                MainFXApplication mainAppWindow = new MainFXApplication();
                try {
                    mainAppWindow.start(stage, getContext());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    LOGGER.error("Exception while fx ", ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});

// Thread waits here until the semaphore gets released
sem.acquire();
```

Comment: Could you please file a bug at http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/

Comment: This is clearly a bug so you should report it on jira directly - there is little chance that you will get an answer on SO.

Comment: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-32501?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel

Comment: Are you calling PlatformImpl.startup() somewhere in your app?

Comment: WHich OS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ultimately happens because QuantumToolkit.pulseTimer.stop() is not called in the process of exiting.
The WinMM calls glass Timer::StaticTimeCallback timer callback while the glass.dll is already unloaded. 
There will be comming out a fix for 8

Answer (score 1):

This Probably be a bug from the VM. There are chances of getting this Error due to the memory management issues in your codes.

> The hs_err_pid712.log file should contain some information about where
>   the problem happened.

VM bugs are mostly caused by the *garbage collection*.

> Log section should show you if the garbage was running at the time of
>   the crash.  The VM is also much more likely to crash in a low memory(mostly the memmory   gets filled)
>   situation than otherwise. Hook into the heap section for more details.